# Installing Digital ID in outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, certificate

I got a Digital ID `user.crt` from `comodo` and installed it in my computer.

Now, I want to add this inside my Microsoft Outlook 2013 to sign my emails.
I followed the steps in the following article, https://support.quovadisglobal.com/kb/a416/how-do-i-install-my-digital-certificate-into-outlook-2013-to-encrypt-email-or-digitally-sign-emails.aspx however, I can't add the certificate and I get the following window every time I try adding.

[image]

With this settings, whenever I try sending an email, I get the below window, from which I also browse to select my Digital ID or certificate but get I get that there are no Certs available installed, but in fact they are. Check the image below.

[image]

Comment: @Ramhound doing so gets me to a website from which I obtained the Digital ID.